# Installed Ubuntu 16.04, can't find bootable device error

Tags: 16.04, grub2, boot-repair

I have run boot-repair and attempted to fix this by changing the boot order in BIOS and disabled the SECURED BOOT .

I also went in to save the shim file as a trusted source by going into the EFI tree, selecting  and selecting the shim file from the list.

I'm on an Acer Aspire E-15.  I previously had Ubuntu 17.04 on this machine but had to downgrade b/c Ubuntu discontinued service on 17.04.

Here's my Pastebin from the Boot Repair Utility:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/26455063/

I also get this instruction from Boot-Repair:
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda1/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file!

I have tried to research this but I'm still relatively new on Linux (and as a devleoper). I have kind of a pressing deadline and kinda need some help.  I don't wanna make things worse.

Please let me know if further info is required.  I am currently in Ubuntu after booting off my USB.  Let me know what other diagnostic info I should run.  I am definitely looking for tools and info that will help me better understand these problems.

It seems that the error occurs when BIOS is trying to hand the process off to GRUB, but for the life of me, I can't figure out what to do.

I just ran this.

Here's the output of sudo efibootmgr -v:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0007,0006,0000,0001,0002,0003,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* grubx64efi    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(1,GPT,c37adb46-d040-4d9f-a35e-762e7eb3a993,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)A01 ..
Boot0001* bootx64efi    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Sata(2,0,0)/HD(1,GPT,5010c24e-500a-4a49-ac3e-11ff0465388f,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\Boot\bootx64.efi)A01 ..
Boot0002* mmx64efi  PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Sata(2,0,0)/HD(1,GPT,5010c24e-500a-4a49-ac3e-11ff0465388f,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\mmx64.efi)A01 ).
Boot0003* yes   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Sata(2,0,0)/HD(1,GPT,5010c24e-500a-4a49-ac3e-11ff0465388f,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)A01 9.
Boot0004* Unknown Device:   HD(1,GPT,f12cbd92-6d5a-4510-9fce-b0b44bd5f83c,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0005* Unknown Device:   HD(1,GPT,e81fed6b-c3d1-4ea4-ae38-83bfe129b045,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0006* Linux HD(1,MBR,0x21,0x2de0dc,0x1240)/File(\EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0007* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,f12cbd92-6d5a-4510-9fce-b0b44bd5f83c,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
```

Comment: on some  Acer models, it is required that you enter the firmware settings and select shimx64.efi as trusted for execution.

Comment: Thanks, I think I did do that, I am updating the post accordingly:

Comment: Another possible issue, I have seen some EFI systems require that the EFI partition be partition 2, because they put a system recovery as partition 1. According to the EFI standard it shouldn't matter where the ESP is; however, specific implementations don't always fully meet standards.

Comment: @ravery how would I investigate that?  Perhaps I should contact Acer?

Comment: perhaps, the only way I know to investigate is to reinstall with the ESP as partition 2

Comment: Hmmmm.  I previously had Ubuntu 17.04 installed on this machine with no problem.   I'm going to look before I do anything like that just yet.  Thanks.

Comment: does your system allow OS selection for boot or only device selection?

Comment: I am not sure how to answer that.  How could I tell?

Comment: open the firmware setting and look at boot order settings, does it list OS or just devices. I assume that it allows OS selection because of trusted boot execution but I want to be sure.

Comment: It just lists devices when I access Boot priority in the BIOS settings

Answer (score 0):

Since your system only allows device boot, the default media path must be used (/EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi)

Fist let's clean up some. boot from your LiveCD and use efibootmgr to remove boot entries 0000 thru 0007:

```
efibootmgr -b 0000 -B
```

You have to delete each one at a time.

Next, use gparted to temporarily remove the ESP flag on the efi partition so we can mount it. Delete /EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi Now, copy the contents of /EFI/ubuntu to /EFI/BOOT. Rename shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi. Unmount the efi partition and reset the ESP flag.

Reboot and enter the firmware setting. Set trusted execution for bootx64.efi.
It should now boot.

Comment: oh great, this was something I thought I might need but couldn't figure out how to start.

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo efibootmgr -b 0007 -B
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 0 seconds
No BootOrder is set; firmware will attempt recovery

Comment: I don't really know what gparted is or any of the steps you advise.   I am reading it like this:  1) use gparted to temporarily remove ESP flag (I don't know what this is, will be googling it)  2) I ran "sudo gparted" then ran Delete /EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi  3)  I assume I have to figure out some kind of command to copy contents from one folder to another in gparted, like maybe "Copy /EFI/Ubuntu  /EFI/BOOT"  ???  4) Unmount EFI Partition  5) Reset flag (I have to google #4 & #5 also)

Comment: you can copy using the file manager. If you can mount the EFI partition the the ESP flag isn't set. THIS is the boot error. the EFI partition has to be marked as the ESP (EFI system partition). set the flag using gparted....delete is not a linux command....mounting and unmounting can be done with gparted.

Comment: Ok, I was able to remove the ESP flag in gparted.  How do I go about finding the EFI/BOOT directory?  Sorry, I am just spacing out on this.   Isn't that something I need to be in grub or rescue or something like that?

Comment: mount the efi partition

Comment: The EFI partition in my machine is SDB1, so I unchcked 'ESP' flag, mounted using "sudo mount /DEV/SDB1 /mnt", then checked the ESP flag again  and I still got the same boot error...